# Sequence under quasi isometry

Tags: real-analysis, geometric-group-theory

Suppose ($x_n$) is a divergent sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ and $\phi$ is an Quasi-Isometry from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ then we have to show that ($\phi(x_n)$) can not oscillate.
 If ($\phi(x_n)$) oscillate finitely then it will be bounded and by definition we get a contradiction but if it oscillate infinitely then i am stuck to write the rigorous argument. Intuitively it seems to be clear.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Can you tell us what exactly is your definition of  a divergent sequence and the definition of a quasi-isometry?

Comment: What do you mean by "oscillate" as opposed to "oscillate finitely"? Is there some kind of nonfinite oscillation, and if so can you define it for us?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasi-isometry Correctly stated, the exercise probably consists in asking to prove that if $x_n$ tends to $+\infty$ or tends to $-\infty$, then the sign of $f(x_n)$ is eventually constant.

Comment: divergent means $(x_n)$ tends to + infinity or - infinity . finite oscillate means all terms of sequence come from a finite set fro example the $((-1)^n)$ and for infinite oscillation see the sequence $((-1)^nn)$

Comment: Does it mean that a sequence is infinitely oscillating if it is not bounded below nor above?

Comment: @MichalBuran you are right